# Can I apply custom labels to a Datadog pie chart widget?

Tags: datadog-dashboard

I have a pie chart widget on an incrementor that I populate by grouping on a tag.

I want to have the display labels be a different name or even have a custom color if possible.

Is there a way to do this?